# Blazor Server, DotNetObjectReference can malicious users spam the server?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

As you may know in Blazor you can call the server methods on components by passing the dotnet object reference to the javascript code.
You would do something like
`await dotnetObj.invokeMethodAsync("MyServerMethod")`.
This code is available client side, if you set a breakpoint on the code and use the object from the  browser console, you can do a setTimeout and call that server method a gazillion times, so doesn't this spam the server occupying band? Is this something to be concerned about?

Comment: Not more than any other SPA application, and actually a lot less. All Javascript applications make calls to server APIs. Are you concerned about your React or Angular applications? If anything, Blazor Server is a lot more restrictive because the actual application code isn't sent to the browser at all. Messages are exchanged between browser and server using a single SignalR connection. Even if someone guessed what methods are available, the gazillion calls would be executed sequentially

Comment: That `not more than` though is a valid concern for *all* SPAs. Someone can indeed modify the code of every SPA application, no matter what framework it's written in, bypassing validation or client-side authorization checks. That's why the server APIs always validate calls themselves and use eg throttling to restrict the number of concurrent calls per client.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 
Yeah my doubts are about how the signalr throttle this, i guess.
In the case of jsInvokable you are restricted by the signalr HubOptions.MaximumReceiveMessageSize for the size of the message.
For the amount of calls as you said they are sequentially executed on the server.